# Get Previous Sibling Returns Current Sibling

Tags: c#, xml

My objective is to get the previous element in the xml file and display it accordingly. 
Unforunatly, when I use the previous sibling method it returns the current element...

Has anyone had this issue before? And how can this be fixed?

I should note, my objective in this is to search by the "num" attribute in order to adhere to proper coding standards in terms of searching by a unique identifier instead of values which can change.

Also I am aware I mixed up the "xmlappChild.InnerText = txtAppName.txt".

Here is my code:

XML File Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This file contains all the apps, versions, source and destination paths.-->
<applications>
<app num="1" desc="changed">
<appname>ARIA</appname>
<version>V 30</version>
<srcpath>c:\testing\</srcpath>
<dstpath>c:\testing\</dstpath>
</app>
<app num="2" desc="changed">
<appname>testing 123</appname>
<version>V 11</version>
<srcpath>C:\Users\Documents\testing\src</srcpath>
<dstpath>C:\Users\Documents\testing\dst</dstpath>
</app>
</applications>
```

C# Code:

```
//loop through the xml to find what the user has selected in order to overwrite
            foreach (XmlNode xmlApp in xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                //select the num attribute and if they match up...
                if (Convert.ToInt32(xmlApp.Attributes["num"].Value) == currappNum)
                {
                    //get the previous app node
                    xmlPrev = xmlApp.PreviousSibling; << this is where I get the problem

                    //replace the description attribute
                    xmlPrev.Attributes["desc"].Value = txtDesc.Text;

                    //loop though the child nodes in xml app 
                    foreach (XmlNode xmlAppChild in xmlPrev.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        //replace all the info 
                        switch (xmlAppChild.Name)
                        {
                            case "appname":
                                xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtAppName.Text;
                                break;
                            case "version":
                                xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtVersion.Text;
                                break;
                            case "srcpath":
                                xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtSrcPath.Text;
                                break;
                            case "dstpath":
                                xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtDstPath.Text;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    //set the current num
                    currappNum = Convert.ToInt32(xmlPrev.Attributes["num"].Value);
                }
               }
            }
```

Comment: Not sure why that is happening without stepping through it myself. The easiest thing for you to do is set the xmlPrev variable to xmlApp at the end of each iteration. Don't even use PreviousSibling. Just add "xmlPrev = xmlApp" right after the code where you set currappNum. I am not suggesting this as an answer, just a way of achieving the goal.

Comment: But I want the previous element. xmlApp would be the current element ...

Comment: Ill post it in the answer just so you can see the code I had in mind. It wont answer the question of "why PreviousSibling is the current node", but should at least solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't explain why you are having the problem with PreviousSibling, but it does accomplish the goal. At the end of each iteration, set xmlPrev to xmlApp. That means for the next iteration, xmlPrev will be equal to the previous node.

```
 var xmlPrev; // im assuming it is declared somewhere up here.      

foreach (XmlNode xmlApp in xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
            //select the num attribute and if they match up...
            if (Convert.ToInt32(xmlApp.Attributes["num"].Value) == currappNum)
            {
                //get the previous app node
                if (xmlPrev == null)
                {
                   //it must be the first element in the loop, so handle this however you need to.
                }

                //replace the description attribute
                xmlPrev.Attributes["desc"].Value = txtDesc.Text;

                //loop though the child nodes in xml app 
                foreach (XmlNode xmlAppChild in xmlPrev.ChildNodes)
                {
                    //replace all the info 
                    switch (xmlAppChild.Name)
                    {
                        case "appname":
                            xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtAppName.Text;
                            break;
                        case "version":
                            xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtVersion.Text;
                            break;
                        case "srcpath":
                            xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtSrcPath.Text;
                            break;
                        case "dstpath":
                            xmlAppChild.InnerText = txtDstPath.Text;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                //set the current num
                currappNum = Convert.ToInt32(xmlPrev.Attributes["num"].Value);
               }
                 xmlPrev = xmlApp; // Set the previous node here. Each time you loop through, the xmlPrev will be set to the previous element in the loop.

           }
        }
```

Comment: Oh okay I see what you are saying now.

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't exactly what you were looking for, but hopefully it at least solves your need.